# R: str_replace not replacing characters, including special characters (+), within string?

Tags: r, special-characters, stringr

How do I remove a " + " sign from a string?

I want to remove `"d12$cig_tax + "` from the following formula:

```
formula = "d12$r_hosp_tp ~ d12$cig_tax + d12$alc_tax + d12$air_temp + d12$x_67 + d12$x_t67 + d12$qs_67 + x_31 "

form2  <- str_replace(formula,paste0("d12$cig_tax"," [^[:alnum:]]")," ")
form2
[1] "d12$r_hosp_tp ~ d12$cig_tax + d12$alc_tax + d12$air_temp + d12$x_67 + d12$x_t67 + d12$qs_67 + x_31 "
```

What I would like it to return is `form2
[1] "d12$r_hosp_tp ~ d12$alc_tax + d12$air_temp + d12$x_67 + d12$x_t67 + d12$qs_67 + x_31 "`

This doesn't work either:

```
str_replace(formula,"d12$cig_tax"," ")
[1] "d12$r_hosp_tp ~ d12$cig_tax + d12$alc_tax + d12$air_temp + d12$x_67 + d12$x_t67 + d12$qs_67 + x_31 "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace based on a fixed string and not a regular expression. To prevent the second argument from being interpreted as a regular expression, use the `fixed` function.

```
str_replace(formula, fixed("d12$cig_tax + ")," ")
# [1] "d12$r_hosp_tp ~  d12$alc_tax + d12$air_temp + d12$x_67 + d12$x_t67 + d12$qs_67 + x_31 "
```